# How to make conditional navigation with bottom navigation view

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I've login flow in my app using `FirebaseUI`.
Currently my flow is like this ->

`MainFragment`:

```
    login_button.setOnClickListener { launchLoginFlow() } //launch the flow through button view
    observeAuthState() //observe whether the user is authenticate or not
```

`MainViewModel`: activate `observeAuthState` in `mainFragment`:

```
val authenticationState = FirebaseUserLiveData().map { user ->
    if (user != null) {
        AuthState.AUTHENTICATED
    } else {
        AuthState.UNAUTHENTICATED
    } }
```

my problem is, How do I prevent from the user to navigate from the `mainFragment` to other fragment if he's not logged in?

with direct navigation it's pretty easy, before the navigation I just check if he is logged in or not.

But how can I check this with bottom navigation view?